# While loop in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I've got following make file:

```
n ?= 10
all:
    while [[ $${n} -gt 0 ]] ; do \
        echo $$n ; \
        ((n = n - 1)) ; \
    done
```

And when I'm trying to run it (`make`), run fails with error:

```
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I can't understand the reason of this fail.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just to note: you are causing your makefile to be extremely non-portable.  Make always invokes recipes using `/bin/sh`.  The recipe you've written is actually a bash script and won't work with a POSIX /bin/sh; it will only work on systems which use /bin/bash as /bin/sh.  Many (most, depending on how you count them) do not.

You can rewrite:

```
n ?= 10
all:
        n=$(n); \
        while [ $${n} -gt 0 ] ; do \
            echo $$n ; \
            n=`expr $$n - 1`; \
        done; \
        true
```

Comment: If you add

SHELL=/bin/bash

to the top of the Makefile, bash will be used : https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html

Comment: Of course.  But why write non-portable code when you don't have to?  If you set `SHELL = /bin/bash` then your makefile will fail on systems that don't provide `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 3):

A rule examines the last return code. If it is nonzero, `make` raises an error.
In your case, the last retrun code is the result of `(( n = n - 1))` for n=2, i.e. 1.

To avoid the error, simply modify the line 5 to:

```
  ((n = n - 1)) || true; \
```